# Intel Wireless Card (9260) speed limited in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, dell

I have a dell XPS 15 (9560) and I've installed an intel wireless AC 9260 WiFi card. I'm running `ubuntu 18.04` with kernel `4.17.14-041714-generic`. I get very realiable wifi connections, but it's extremely slow. After some testing, I found that it won't connect at a link speed higher than 54mb/s as reported in the gnome network manager applet.

I think for some reason the card is connecting at G speeds. The strange thing is my access point is set to WiFi A/N only on the 5GHz band so it shouldn't be possible. I've tried a lot of different askubuntu answers. The access point is set to only allow AES encryption. An interesting thing is this excerpt from `iw list`:

```
...
Band 2:
    Bitrates (non-HT):
        * 6.0 Mbps
        * 9.0 Mbps
        * 12.0 Mbps
        * 18.0 Mbps
        * 24.0 Mbps
        * 36.0 Mbps
        * 48.0 Mbps
        * 54.0 Mbps
    Frequencies:
        * 5180 MHz [36] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5200 MHz [40] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
...
```

It appears Ubuntu thinks the card can only do up to 54mb/s. My Galaxy S9+ connects fine at 300mpbs+ so I don't believe it's an access point issue. Any idea how I can get a connection speed above 54mb/s? Thanks heaps!

### **UPDATE:**

After a recent string of updates it seems to have fixed itself.

Answer (score 1):

> It appears Ubuntu thinks the card can only do up to 54mb/s.

Not Ubuntu. It is the driver; the support for your card is [fairly new](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=899101) (it was added to debian july 2018) so it might just be lacking support for this.

2 things to try:

On [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2387479&page=2) there is a suggestion ...

- you need this [patch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git/commit/drivers/net/wireless/intel?id=998ce0330c94eca4b13b8f062b3f0ca9ef9ad6d8).
- try the option `11n_disable=1` or `11n_disable=8`in `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

I would file a bug report on this against [linux-firmware iwlwifi](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware).

Answer (score 0):

I'm running on an XPS15 9570 with the same Intel 9260 Card and noticed the same behavior.

In my own testing, nothing worked for me until I updated the kernel to baseline 4.16.x and performance was restored to normal. Haven't tested with 4.17.x.

Give 4.16 a try and see if it works for you.

Note:
The main downside of updating the kernel for me was breaking from 18.04LTS.