# Is Intel 9260 any good

Tags: wireless

I have an Acer laptop and was running with Killer Networking 152t WiFi card but I am constantly having problems with my wireless speed and it does disconnect every now and then. Even though it is a known issue and the Killer Networking have admitted it, their solution doesn't work so I am looking for another WiFi adapter with better signal strength and reliability. I was checking the options and Intel 9260 seems good to me but I don't know if the Linux Support of this card is good.

Comment: There are (were) a few issues -- [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064044/intel-wireless-card-9260-speed-limited-in-ubuntu-18-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064044/intel-wireless-card-9260-speed-limited-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But apparently the driver support is coming to this card and me drivers are fixing the slow speeds. And currently I think it won't be worse than my Killer Wireless adapter.